# Jquery Cookie Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I'm still quite new to this so please bear with me. I have a function which adds a class on a click event, this works fine. But I would also like the clicked function to be saved as a cookie so when that user next visits the site those classes are still there/reapplied. I'm using jquery.cookie for this. My code is as follows.

```
$(".bblue").click(function bblue() {
    $("dl").addClass("bbluebg");
    $("dd .button").addClass("buttonb");
    $('.button img').attr('src',function(i,e){return e.replace("White","DBlue");});
    $.cookie("color", function bblue(){} , { expires: null, path: '/' });
});
```

When I call `$.cookie('color');` is returns `function bblue(){}` but it doesn't run the function when the page loads next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want to store the preference and take action based on that.  Try something like this:

```
// Event-independent color change function
var bblue = function() {
    $("dl").addClass("bbluebg");
    $("dd .button").addClass("buttonb");
    $('.button img').attr('src', $('.button img').replace("White","DBlue"));
}

// Click action
$(".bblue").click(function () {
    // Change the color
    bblue();
    // Store the preference
    $.cookie("color", "blue" , { expires: null, path: '/' });
});

// On page load
$(document).load(function() {
    // If they chose blue before, change the color
    if ($.cookie("color") == "blue") bblue();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The function isn't running again because the user isn't clicking anything when the page reloads. Your function only runs when someone clicks the `.bblue` element.

You need to get the value of the cookie and set classes where appropriate on document ready instead. The classes won't stick, you have to re-apply them. You want to use...

```
$(function() {
    var color = $.cookie("color");

    // Set classes according to color here
});
```

Which will execute and set all the classes once the page is loaded.